# Test urls in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am trying to use something like this write a function in JavaScript that loops through an array of urls. Once a 'pingable' url is found the function should return its index number.

```
function ping(url: string): Promise {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        resolve(response.status === 200);
      },
      (error) => {
        resolve(false);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this with each iteration having to get results from a promise. Any help is appreciated.

I tried a for loop for each of the urls and use the break statement to exit. However break statements are not allowed.

Comment: Sounds like you could use `Promise.race([ping(url1), ping(url2), ping(url3),...])` to get the result of whichever answers first. Alternatively something like `Promise.all([ping(url1), ping(url2), ping(url3),...])` to get an array of all results. In both cases I would probaby return something else from `resolve`, perhaps the url on success. 

Oh, and would make sense to use reject instead of `resolve(false)`. `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... (error) => reject(error)) }`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#promise_concurrency

Comment: @cYrixmorten I think you want Promise.any, (not Promise.race) because you want the first url that you can successfully ping, not just the first one that settles (not just the first url that happens to be decided whether or not it is pingable)

Comment: Does the order of the array matter? Like, should the first result take priority? Or is the order arbitrary and you'll accept whichever URL happens to return a result first?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning more data instead of just a `boolean`.  This is untested, but if you pass the URL and the index to this function, then when the promise is resolved or rejected you can return an object with the index and the result in it.

```
interface IPingableResponse {
  index: number;
  pingable: boolean;
}

ping(url: string, idx: number): Promise<IPingableResponse> {
  return new Promise<IPingableResponse> ((resolve) => {
    this.http.get(url, {
      observe: 'response'
    }).subscribe((response) => {
      resolve({
        index: idx,
        pingable: response.status === 200
      });
    }, (error) => {
      resolve({
        index: idx,
        pingable: false
      });
    });
  });
}
```